# Having problem whenever code encounters the line cv2.waitKey(1) and is dumping the core

Tags: python-3.x, linux, image-processing, ubuntu-18.04, imshow

I have written a python code that runs on Ubuntu 18.04 and captures a live video from the webcam and is displaying the frames. However, there are two problems noted.

1. cv2.imshow does not work without being followed by key = cv2.waitKey().
2. When I run if key == ord('q'), my code dumps the core and shuts down the code.
3. When I use the internal webcam cv2.videoCapture(0) the code works perfectly fine till I press q, it dumps the core the moment it encounters cv2.waitKey.
4. When I use an USB camera on deviceid1 with cv2.videoCapture(1, CAP_DSHOW) which works perfectly fine on windows, the code hangs or just shows me the ubuntu terminal. When I use cv2.videoCapture(1) the first frame gets captured and then the error is diplayed that says...
   "
   ASSERT:  "false" in file qasciikey.cpp, line 501
   Aborted (core dumped)
5. On further investigation I have learnt that there  is also an error in reading an input from the keyboard. since I am trying to quit the program using the code,
   'if key == ord("q"):
   print ("Window Closing")
   vid.release
   cv2.destroyAllWindows
   '
   I was getting an error

> Segmentation  fault (core dumped)
> I ran debug through gnu debugger, gdb
> ' gdb/python3
> (gdb) run /file-path/file.py '
> The code started working then the moment I pressed q to end the code I got the following fault
> Thread 1 "python3" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> 0x00007fff4a1b8798 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0
> (gdb) bt
> gave the following output

```
`
#0  0x00007fff4a1b8798 in  () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0
#1  0x00007fff4a1b8c37 in xkb_state_key_get_level ()
at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0
#2  0x00007fff4a1b95c6 in xkb_state_key_get_syms ()
at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0
#3  0x00007fff4a1b9b88 in xkb_state_key_get_one_sym ()
at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0
#4  0x00007fff415a8465 in  ()
at /home/rishi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins/platforms/../../../../opencv_contrib_python.libs/libQt5XcbQpa-70670cdb.so.5.15.0
#5  0x00007fff415a87c9 in  ()
at /home/rishi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins/platforms/../../../../opencv_contrib_python.libs/libQt5XcbQpa-70670cdb.so.5.15.0
#6  0x00007fff415a313e in QtOpenCVPython::QXcbConnection::handleXcbEvent(xcb_generic_event_t*) ()
at /home/rishi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins/platforms/../../../../opencv_contrib_python.libs/libQt5XcbQpa-70670cdb.so.5.15.0
#7  0x00007fff415a35a6 in QtOpenCVPython::QXcbConnection::processXcbEvents(QtOpenCVPython::QFlags<QtOpenCVPython::QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) ()
at /home/rishi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins/platforms/../../../../opencv_contrib_python.libs/libQt5XcbQpa-70670cdb.so.5.15.0
#8  0x00007fff415caa93 in  ()
at /home/rishi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins/platforms/.---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
```

./../../../opencv_contrib_python.libs/libQt5XcbQpa-70670cdb.so.5.15.0
#9  0x00007fffece0b537 in g_main_context_dispatch () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#10 0x00007fffece0b770 in  () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#11 0x00007fffece0b7fc in g_main_context_iteration () at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#12 0x00007fffeeb63061 in QtOpenCVPython::QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QtOpenCVPython::QFlagsQtOpenCVPython::QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag) ()
at /home/rishi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/../opencv_contrib_python.libs/libQt5Core-d92f2856.so.5.15.0
#13 0x00007ffff33ebc17 in  () at /home/rishi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#14 0x00007ffff33e721a in  () at /home/rishi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#15 0x00007ffff22d1b93 in  () at /home/rishi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#16 0x000000000050a5a5 in  ()
#17 0x000000000050bf44 in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault ()
#18 0x0000000000507cd4 in  ()
#19 0x000000000050ae13 in PyEval_EvalCode ()
#20 0x0000000000635262 in  ()
#21 0x0000000000635317 in PyRun_FileExFlags ()
#22 0x0000000000638acf in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags ()
#23 0x0000000000639671 in Py_Main ()
#24 0x00000000004b0e40 in main ()`

MY CODE IS AS FOLLOWS

```
# You may need to restart your runtime prior to this, to let your installation take effect
# Some basic setup

(Importing the necessary functions)

vid = './test/drone_1.mp4'
video_visualizer = VideoVisualizer(metadata, ColorMode.IMAGE)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vid)


print("Processing Video....")
while(cap.isOpened()):
   ret, frame = cap.read()
   if ret == True:
      print('Got a frame!')
      predictions = predictor(frame)
      vis_frame = video_visualizer.draw_instance_predictions(frame,   predictions["instances"].to("cpu"))
      cv2.imshow('Frame', vis_frame.get_image())
      key = cv2.waitKey(1)
      for i in range(len(predictions['instances'])):
         print(calc_centroid(predictions["instances"][i].pred_boxes.tensor))

   else:  
       break
   if key == ord("q"):
      print("[INFO] closing...")
      cap.release()  # release web camera
      cv2.destroyAllWindows()  # it is not mandatory in this application

print("Done")
cap.release()
```

---

Based on @MarkSetchell's observation I changed my code to

```
print("Processing Video....")
while(cap.isOpened()):
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  if ret == True:
    print('Got a frame!')
    predictions = predictor(frame)
    vis_frame = video_visualizer.draw_instance_predictions(frame, predictions["instances"].to("cpu"))

    cv2.imshow('Frame', vis_frame.get_image())
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('q'):
      print("[INFO] closing...")
      cap.release()  # release web camera
      cv2.destroyAllWindows()

  if ret == False: 
    break
```

The error still remains Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: `CAP_DSHOW` uses Microsoft [DirectShow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectShow) framework. DirectShow is not supported by Linux.

Comment: I also tried to use cv2.videoCapture(1, cv2.CAP_V4L2) this time the first frame gets captured and the when the code encounters the line key = cv2.waitKey(1) the code abruptly ends with the error...  "ASSERT: "false" in file qasciikey.cpp, line 501 Aborted (core dumped)..... further whenever im trying to read a key with 'key =cv2.waitKey()' 'if key == ord('q')' whenever the code encounters this line again it says "segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: I don't think I can help you. I don't have much experience using OpenCV with Linux (I am using Windows).

Comment: You don't seem to show any code, so it's extremely difficult to help.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have added the code, actually was having a bit of problem uploading it. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There's an error in your logic. `if key==ord("q")` belongs above `else`. Otherwise you potentially test `key` without having set it. You also can call `cap.release()` twice.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I amended the code in the following manner, print("Processing Video....")
while(cap.isOpened()):
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  if ret == True:
    print('Got a frame!')
    predictions = predictor(frame)
    vis_frame = video_visualizer.draw_instance_predictions(frame, predictions["instances"].to("cpu"))
    
  cv2.imshow('Frame', vis_frame.get_image())
  key = cv2.waitKey(1)
  if key == ord('q'):
    print("[INFO] closing...")
    cap.release()  # release web camera
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

  if ret == False: 
    break

Comment: @MarkSetchell It still shows the same error the moment i press 'q', >Segmentation fault (core dumped)....

Comment: Your code is still incorrect. You can now call `vis_frame.get_image()` without having previously set `vis_frame`.

Comment: Have corrected that though ret == False isnt occuring in the case of my code to encounter the error you mentioned. However, even after correcting it I am still getting the same error. Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Any help on this? I really am stumped as to what could be the fault.